# Get rid of automatic context menu in Edge?

Tags: context-menu, microsoft-edge, highlighting

I compulsively highlight text as I read it, and MS Edge (yes, I use Edge) pops in an annoying little context menu automatically. Is there any way to disable this?
[image]
I'm using Edge Chromium 97.0.1072.62
(And yes, I'm aware of [this comic](https://xkcd.com/1271/))

Comment: I find it funny that the menu in question literally has an option titled "[Hide menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuyzZ.png)", and yet...

Comment: @user1686 wow, now I really feel like an idiot. I never actually looked what in it